# How to test Ruby catch/throw using minitest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I've got some pseudo code like this:

```
catch :my_error do
  first_method
  second_method
  third_method
end

def first_method
  if error_condition?
    throw :my_error
  end
end
```

I'm trying to use Minitest to test that the first method properly throws :my_error. My test looks like this:

```
assert_throws :my_error do
  some code in here that ensures error_condition? is true
end
```

When I run this test, Minitest fails the test with:

> Minitest::Assertion: Expected :my_error to have been thrown

If I comment out the catch :my_error invocation, the test passes, but of course I need that code to be there in production. Not sure what the point of "assert_throws" is if it doesn't work with code that has catches in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert_throws` will assert that something has been thrown, so if it is catched by your code, you cannot assert that something has been thrown!

You can assert that a specific method throws, and then that another one that calls this one does not

Or if you change any data in the catch, you can test for this data

Comment: Thanks Geoffroy, that was my understanding too, but seems like that makes "assert_throws" not very useful. It should intercept (catch) higher in the chain, before my production catch code. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It cannot know that something has been thrown if it was caught, so the behavior is expected

You generally throw in one method and catch in another one, so it's an easily testable behavior.

assert_raise works the same way btw.

Comment: The method that throws the error is private and I don't want to test it directly. I figured out another way to test the behavior though. If the throw/catch is not executed then the production code will exception out. So instead I'm testing for the absence of an exception using assert_nothing_raised.